# Create Event with a Generic Type

Tags: c#, events

What i want is to write a class that can send an object by Serializing the type to an Byte[] and on a Event DeSerializing a Byte[] back to the Object.

```
public interface ISource
    {
        event EventHandler<T> myevent;
        void Send<T>(T dataToSend);
    }
```

The Event Codeline is not working in the Compiler but that is what i need.

Example implementation:

```
public class Source : ISource
{
    ISerialPort _port;

    public Source (ISerialPort port)
    {
        _port = port;
    }

    public event EventHandler<T> myevent;

    public void Send<T>(T dataToSend)
    {
        //Converts type to an Byte[] with Serialisation
        //And send the Data
        _port.Send(ConvertedByteArray);
    }
}
```

The send part is working without a Problem, because i can precify the Type when 
calling the Send method.

```
obj.Send<List<String>>(myList);
```

Now i want to create the other direction(Byte[] -> T) with an Event.

So that i specify the value of the EventDataType at subscribing to the Event in the Source class.

Is there an elegant solution to it?

I not want to specify the type like "public class"
because i want that the class can receive and send different obj/types

Regards
rubiktubik

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the T in
Interface Declaration and Class Declaration too.

```
interface ISource<T> where T : EventArgs
{
    event EventHandler<T> MyEvent;
    void Send<G>(G dataToSend);
}
public class Source<T> : ISource<T> where T : EventArgs
{

    public event EventHandler<T> MyEvent;

    public void Send<T>(T dataToSend)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Create a derived Class from `EventArgs` to pass in.